# Android - Layout and Layout-land not changing right away

Tags: android, landscape-portrait, tabbed

I have a simple tabbed application and I would like to change the layout when the device is in landscape mode. I have found how to do that but it does not update to the new layout out until I go between tabs.

This is not the intended behavior any way to fix this?

Comment: Can you post your approach you followed ??

Comment: I have not really tried anything other than trying to recreate the fragment on the change from land. to port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I need to recreate the tabs to change the layout file that they were using. I used the onConfigurationChanged method to text for the change in orientation.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

Then I just recreated the tabs like I created them the first time and everything worked just as planned.